502 Bad Gateway Error on wp-admin and wp-login.php with PHP 7.4 on High Traffic WordPress Site
I'm having some trouble with my server setup for a high-traffic WordPress site, which I configured without using any control panel. Everything seems to be working fine, except when I try to access wp-login.php or wp-admin, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.
I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Some of the sites are running PHP 7.4, while others are using PHP 8.1. I haven't tested it on PHP 8.1 yet, but on PHP 7.4, accessing wp-admin and wp-login.php consistently results in a 502 Bad Gateway error.
my www.conf on php 7.4 and php 8.1
php 8.1
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
php 7.4
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
My NGINX Directive
    location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;
    try_files \$uri =404;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # Use PHP 7.4 FPM for example.com
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "max_execution_time=3600; upload_max_filesize=100M; post_max_size=100M;";
}

==
    location ~/(wp-admin/|wp-login.php) {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host \$http_host;
    proxy_set_header Host \$host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000; # Use PHP 7.4 FPM for example.com
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 7200;
    proxy_send_timeout 7200;
    proxy_read_timeout 7200;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}

==
Am I missing something, please advise :)

Close vote because it is not a programming question but a server configuration question / server hacked issue. Not for this site.
Down vote because spamming unrelated tags bash, shell.

Nginx rules map one URL to one rule.
Why do you have a separate rule for wp-admin/|wp-login.php? In the case of nginx configuration, if it matches in one place, it doesn't look for other places.
So if the location ~/(wp-admin/|wp-login.php) syntax is above location ~ \.php$, only proxy_* rules will be executed according to this rule. If for some reason you only need proxy_* rules for the admin, you need to put all the rules in location ~ \.php$ together.
